# Retrieving the profile photo for a user

Tags: apex, user, images

Does anybody know how I can retrieve the profile picture for a user from salesforce? I need access to the url of the picture.

Is it stored somewhere as a field value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use user's `FullPhotoUrl` and `SmallPhotoUrl` fields

VF code:

```
       <apex:page controller="cls_PhotoUrl">
            <apex:form>
                <apex:image value="{!Photolink}"/>
           </apex:form>
        </apex:page>
```

Controller code:

```
Public class cls_PhotoUrl
{
     public string Photolink{get;set;}
     Public cls_PhotoUrl()
     {
         User u = [Select u.SmallPhotoUrl, u.FullPhotoUrl 
                     From User u where u.id=:Userinfo.getUserid()];
        Photolink = u.FullPhotoUrl;
     }
}
```

Comment: I will try it in a moment, you are awesome!